# Graded readers for Portuguese?

Tags: electronic-resources, physical-resources, graded-readers, portuguese

Extensive reading or reading for pleasure is an excellent way of getting a lot of "comprehensible input" in a foreign language. Graded readers provide this type of comprehensible. Are there any graded readers for Portuguese? And where can they be found?

Answer (score 1):

The German publisher Compact currently has one "**Lernkrimi**" ("crime story for learning") for Portuguese: [*Morte no Tejo*](https://www.lernkrimi.de/portugiesisch/morte-no-tejo-kurzkrimis.html), for level A1. Like other Lernkrimis in this series, some words and expressions that may pose problems are printed in red and translated into German (on the same page). The book also contains exercises (almost on every other page).

The German publisher dtv has a few [**bilingual Portuguese-German books**](https://www.dtv.de/buecher-belletristik-zweisprachig/portugiesisch/c-454). These books only contain text (Portuguese on the left side, with German on the facing page); there is no CD with a recording of the text, and there are no exercises. There are currently three titles:

- [*Primeiras Leituras. Erste portugiesische Lesestücke*](https://www.dtv.de/buch/maria-de-fatima-mesquita-sternal-michael-sternal-primeiras-leituras-erste-portugiesische-lesestuecke-9412/), edited by Maria de Fatima Mesquita-Sternal & Michael Sternal (2002),
- [*Microcontos. Minigeschichten aus Brasilien*](https://www.dtv.de/buch/luisa-costa-hoelzl-microcontos-minigeschichten-aus-brasilien-9518/) ("mini stories from Brazil"), edited by Luísa Costa Hölzl (2013),
- [*Contos Portugueses Modernos. Moderne portugiesische Kurzgeschichten*](https://www.dtv.de/buch/ulrike-schuldes-contos-portugueses-modernos-moderne-portugiesische-kurzgeschichten-9343/) ("modern Portuguese short stories"), edited by Ulrike Schuldes (1996).

Irineu De Oliveira published *Short Stories in Portuguese: My Daily Routine* through CreateSpace (Amazon's self-publishing service). This book is entirely in Portuguese (without translations). Each chapter is followed by a set of question that check what you have learnt. The book is available in print, in Kindle format and as audio book. The second volume in this series is *Short Stories in Portuguese 2: My Childhood Dream*.